# how can I prevent Nested tables inside ng-repeat from populating in every row?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

OK, so I want to create a dynamic nested hierarchy of tables. I get they data no problem, but using ng-repeat at each level causes the parent table to insert child data for a specific row into each row of the parent table. I want to prevent this, I have tried using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end, however, because of the table nesting I cannot add the end tag in an appropriate place to stop the repeat.

**UPDATE**
Let me clarify a bit here, I have 3 nested tables, the top level table has list of groups, the first child table is a list of all of the items that belong to a specific group in the parent table. When the user clicks the expand button, I populate the child table based on which row in the parent table was clicked, this is OK, however the child table now shows up in each of the parent table rows instead of just the row that was clicked.

**Plunker Link**
http://plnkr.co/edit/RVOnf9wBF3TzXauzvMfF

**HTML:**

```
<table id="sicGroupTable" class="RadGrid_Metro">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <td>Sic Code Group</td>
       </tr>
   </thead>
       <tbody ng-repeat="group in sicCodeGroup">
           <tr class="rgRow">
               <td class="rgExpandCol"><img class="rgExpand" ng-click="expandRow(group.GroupId)" ng-model="hideTwoDigitSub" /></td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="SelectGroup" /></td>
               <td>{{group.GroupName}}</td>
           </tr>
           <tr ng-hide="hideTwoDigitSub">
               <td></td>
               <td>
                   <table id="sic2DigitTable" class="RadGrid_Metro">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th>2 digit sic Code</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                           <tbody>
                               <tr ng-repeat="twoDigitSic in twoDigitSicCodes" class="rgRow">
                                   <td class="rgExpandCol"><img class="rgExpand" ng-click="expandRow(twoDigitSic.SicCode)" /></td>
                                   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Select2DigitSicCode" /></td>
                                   <td>{{twoDigitSic.SICCode2}} - {{twoDigitSic.Title}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                 <td>
                                     <table id="sic4DigitTable" class="RadGrid_Metro">
                                         <thead>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <th>4 digit sic code</th>
                                             </tr>
                                         </thead>
                                             <tbody>
                                                 <tr class="rgRow">
                                                     <td class="rgExpandCol"><img class="rgExpand" ng-click="expandRow(sicCode.SicCode)" /></td>
                                                     <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Select2DigitSicCode" /></td>
                                                     <td>{{sicCode.SicCode}} - {{sicCode.Title}}</td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module("apptSetting", ['ngResource'])

app.factory('dataFactory',
    function ($resource) {
        return {
            getSicGroups: $resource('../Packages/GetJsonSicCodeGroups'),
            expandRow: $resource('../Packages/GetExpandedRowData')
        }
    });

app.controller('aPackageController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function ($scope,  dataFactory) {
function init() {
    $scope.hideTwoDigitSub = true;
    $scope.hideFourdigitsub = true;
}
$scope.sicCodeGroup = dataFactory.getSicGroups.query({}, isArray = true);
$scope.twoDigitSicCodes = null;
$scope.expandRow = function (groupId, sicCode) {
    if (groupId != undefined)
    {
        $scope.twoDigitSicCodes = dataFactory.expandRow.query({ GroupId: groupId }, isArray = true);
        $scope.hideTwoDigitSub = false;
        if (sicCode != null && sicCode != undefined && sicCode != "") {
            if (sicCode.length == 2) {
                $scope.hideTwoDigitSub = false;
                $scope.twoDigitSicCodes = dataFactory.Get2DigitSicCodes.query({ GroupId: groupId }, isArray = true);
            }
        }
    }     
}
    init();
}])
```

Comment: provide a **working plunker**. your description is **not clear**: *"causes the parent table to insert child data for a specific row into each row of the parent table"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a single boolean `hideTwoDigitSub` to control all the `tr`s created by your `ngRepeat`:

```
<tr ng-hide="hideTwoDigitSub">
```

So when you set `$scope.hideTwoDigitSub = false;` every `ngHide` within your `ngRepeat` gets that false and thus all the `tr` elements are shown.

**Radio Button Fix**

Instead of using a boolean I'd set `hideTwoDigitSub` to the `groupId` for the row you want to show (and maybe rename `hideTwoDigitSub` to `showTwoDigitSub` since the variable now indicates which row to show).

So inside your `expandRow()` function I'd set which row to show by changing:

```
$scope.hideTwoDigitSub = false;
```

to

```
$scope.hideTwoDigitSub = groupId;
```

And change the above `tr` to:

```
<tr ng-hide="hideTwoDigitSub != group.GroupId">
```

So the row will be hidden unless your control variable `hideTwoDigitSub` is not equal to the current groups `GroupId`.

**Or** it might be clearer to use `ngShow` (note I changed the  `hideTwoDigitSub` to `showTwoDigitSub` in this example since it's clearer):

```
<tr ng-show="showTwoDigitSub == group.GroupId">
```

[radio button plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D3AbpJbiI4dWeY3AiNiT?p=preview)

**Checkbox solution**

This approach is easiest done switching `hideTwoDigitSub` to `showTwoDigitSub`- so everything below assumes that.

For this approach, inside `init()` I'd set your control variable to be an array:

```
$scope.showTwoDigitSub=[];
```

And then toggle the appropriate control inside `expand`:

```
$scope.showTwoDigitSub[groupId] = !$scope.showTwoDigitSub[groupId];
```

And use the array inside your html:

```
<tr ng-show="showTwoDigitSub[group.GroupId]">
```

[checkbox plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R8ADVPJFlWiCk3Lt7XgO?p=preview)

Comment: I can appreciate this for expanding a single row that is great, but all rows can be expanded, and all sub tables will have unique data and can be expanded even further. So it doesn't quite answer the whole problem.

Comment: Are you intending to also change the "expand" button into a "shrink" when it's expanded- so the user can toggle?  In either case it's easy to turn `showTwoDigitSub` into an array of booleans - one entry per row.  Here's [that plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D3AbpJbiI4dWeY3AiNiT?p=preview) which assumes the button is a toggle

Comment: Yep, that does what I want, after your first answer it was where I went, thanks for the answer!